# realm 複数のプロパティ(項目)にPrimaryKey、Indexedの属性は可能でしょうか？

Tags: realm

下記のように、クラス(テーブル)に設定する複数のプロパティ(項目)に対して、PrimaryKeyや、Indexedの属性を付けることは可能でしょうか。可能でしたら構文を教えていただけると幸いです。
ご教授の程、よろしくお願いいたします。

※code1、code2に対してPrimaryKeyを付け、code3、code4に対してIndexedを付けるイメージとなります。

```
class MasterTable : RealmObject
{
     [PrimaryKey]
    public int code1 { get; set; }
    public string code2 { get; set; }

    [Indexed]
    public string code3 { get; set; }
    public string code4 { get; set; }

    public string firstname { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

PrimaryKeyは１種類のオブジェクトにつき１つだけしか指定できません。

Indexedは複数のプロパティに指定できます。

例でいうと、

```
class MasterTable : RealmObject
{
     [PrimaryKey]
    public int code1 { get; set; }
    public string code2 { get; set; }

    [Indexed]
    public string code3 { get; set; }
    [Indexed]
    public string code4 { get; set; }

    public string firstname { get; set; }

}
```

のように書けばいいです。

もし複数のプロパティでプライマリキーを表現したいなら、例えば`code1`と`code2`を連結したプロパティを作成して（自分で`code1`と`code2`を連結した値が入るように実装する）、そのプロパティをプライマリキーとして指定する、という方法があります。

Comment: 返信が遅くなり申し訳ありません。ご教授いただき誠にありがとうございました。アドバイスいただいたようにプライマリキーは連結した値を代入する方向で検討します。